# Date icon issue in DateTimePicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issue in CSS.

I created a date field using `DateTimePicker`, then I added one date icon to the Date field as a background image. Now the issue is that date icon is coming in text field. When I click on that icon date popup will open in those two time fields (hours and minutes). There also that date icon is coming, that time fields are also text fields only.

I tried CSS selectors like `:first`, `::parent`, `:first-child`, `:first-of-type`, `:nth-child(1)`, but nothing is working. I want date icon only on text field not in time field.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Hi. Please add some of your Code (or even better provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Fabin, I don't have code write know. It is in my office pc. Can u please give me some suggestions,why that error is coming means.

Comment: Hi again. Could you at least show some html code? In general there a bunch of possibilities to select a certain input. You can select by ID, class, pseudo-classed (as you tried), tag types or attributes. If there was some code shown im sure we could solve this.